# Is there a way to create a strongly typed class at runtime?

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex

How would I create a strongly typed class at runtime (so to be able to create instances of it)? It can't be a proxy.

**Additional Info**:
For example, say I want to create a Person class with first and last where both are Strings.

**Context**
This is for an application that lets you create the data model and custom components at runtime. This is only part of it. I need to be able to have strong typing. If that means going to the server and creating a new SWF on the server with the value objects then loading in the definition at runtime then I would but that is a lot more work if there is an alternative.

Comment: What are you asking here?  Actionscript 3 is strongly typed to begin with.  What kind of class are you trying to create and what is the question?  You need to be more specific if you expect a real answer.

Comment: Are you trying to create a completely new class at runtime?  Or do you just need to create a new instance of a class that was defined at compile time?

Comment: @flextras - It would be a completely new class at runtime. For example, say I want to create a Person class with first and last where both are Strings.

Comment: @zzzzBov @ batkins - This is a legitimate question. The qualifier here is at runtime not compile time. There is a big difference.

Comment: @1.21gigawatts, I'm aware that you *have* a question, but what you haven't provided is a context. Additionally, Flash is an ECMAScript variant, so I highly recommend taking advantage of the loose typing that's available in object literals.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

AS3Commons-Bytecode lets you generate classes at runtime: http://www.as3commons.org/as3-commons-bytecode/emit.html